# Tight VC bound for agnostic learning

Tags: reference-request, lg.learning, vc-dimension

The following result is [supposedly known](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf#page=72). However, the proofs I am able to find all prove a weaker result with an extra log factor. Where can I find the proof of the tight bound?

> **Theorem.** Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a class of functions $h : \mathcal{X} \to \{-1,+1\}$ with [VC dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension) $d<\infty$. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a distribution on $\mathcal{X} \times \{-1,1\}$ and let $(X_1,Y_1), \cdots, (X_n,Y_n)$ be independent samples from $\mathcal{D}$. Let $\varepsilon,\delta>0$.
>
> If $n \geq O\left(\frac{d+\log(1/\delta)}{\varepsilon^2}\right)$, then $$\mathbb{P}\left[\forall h \in \mathcal{H} ~~\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n h(X_i) \cdot Y_i - \underset{(X_*,Y_*) \leftarrow \mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{E}}[h(X_*) \cdot Y_*]\right|\le\varepsilon\right] \ge 1-\delta.$$

---

The (well-known) connection to agnostic learning is as follows. $\mathcal{H}$ is a class of "hypotheses" and $\mathcal{D}$ is some unknown ground truth distribution on attributes $X \in \mathcal{X}$ and labels $Y \in \{-1,+1\}$. You see $n$ samples from $\mathcal{D}$ and want to be sure that any hypothesis that labels the sample well (i.e. $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n h(X_i) \cdot Y_i$ is large) also labels the ground truth well (i.e. $\underset{(X_*,Y_*) \leftarrow \mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{E}}[h(X_*) \cdot Y_*]$ is also large). The above theorem says that if $n \geq O\left(\frac{\mathsf{VCdim}(\mathcal{H})+\log(1/\delta)}{\varepsilon^2}\right)$ then with probability $\ge 1-\delta$, for all hypotheses the error on the sample and the error on the distribution are within $\varepsilon$.

The proofs that I can find relating VC dimension to uniform convergence all include an extra log factor. That is, they prove a bound of $n \geq O\left(\frac{\mathsf{VCdim}(\mathcal{H}) \cdot \log(\mathsf{VCdim}(\mathcal{H})/\varepsilon)+\log(1/\delta)}{\varepsilon^2}\right)$. This is achieved by applying the [Perles-Sauer-Shelah lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sauer%E2%80%93Shelah_lemma) and a clever union bound. For the simple case where $\mathsf{VCdim}(\mathcal{H})=\log|\mathcal{H}|$, this just follows from Hoeffding's inequality and a union bound.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a proof of the tight and general result, despite looking for several hours. Surely someone can point me to the right source!

Comment: Isn't Chapter 28 of the book you have linked to proving this theorem as you state?  Where is this weaker theorem proved as you say?

Comment: @gradstudent Chapter 28 proves the weaker version.

Comment: Can you specify which theorem of Chapter 28 you are referring to?

Comment: @gradstudent This is in section 28.1 -- there is no theorem statement, but what they show is eq. (28.1).

Comment: Whats confusing me is that Theorem 6.8 as stated on page 73 seems to give the tight bounds already as you want.

Comment: @gradstudent yes, the statement is what I want, but the proof is not. If you read the fist few lines of section 28.1, it is clear that they prove something weaker than they state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was proven in

> M. Talagrand. *Sharper bounds for Gaussian and empirical processes.* The Annals of Probability, pages 28–76, 1994.

This is mentioned in e.g. [this paper (Section 1.1.2)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.00932), which does a pretty good job (in my opinion) of summarizing the landscape.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! I have some reading to do, including chasing some references.

Comment: So it seems that the key to the improvement is a generalization of Sauer's lemma by [Haussler](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/da08/19e556c860aa43496944f6592bfca0024759.pdf). Namely, rather than just bounding the cardinality of the hypothesis class, he bounds the covering number. This extra geometric information is enough to improve the bound via chaining.

Comment: You can get asymptotically optimal (up to constants) agnostic PAC bounds without the full power of Haussler's result. Older results of Dudley and Pollard suffice. See my lecture notes here: https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~asml162/Class_Material

Comment: Thanks, @Aryeh ! That is considerably simpler. Indeed, we just need the covering number to be $(1/\varepsilon)^{O(d)}$, rather than Haussler's $O(1/\varepsilon)^d$.